# Date::Calc - format the day and month

Tags: perl, date

All I am trying to do here is if the day or month is a single digit, to add a zero in 
the front of it.  Right now it prints out the date as 201188, and I am looking for 
20110808.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Date::Calc qw(Add_Delta_Days); 
my (undef, undef, undef, $day, $month, $year) = localtime(); 
$year +=1900; 
$month +=1; 
($year, $month, $day ) = Add_Delta_Days($year, $month, $day, -3)
if ($month =~ /\d{1}/){
    s/$month/0$month/
}  
if ($day =~/\d{1}/){ 
    s/$day/0$day/
}
print $year,$month,$day;
```

Comment: Your if-statements do not make sense. First off, they will always contain one digit (1 or 2), so the if-statements will always be true. Second, you are performing a substitution on the `$_` variable, not `$month` and `$day`.

Comment: @TLP, he posted the code he has now, which doesn't work (for the reasons you mention).  That's his question.  Your comment should be an answer instead.

Comment: actually I think that @TLP pointed out something that I needed to understand. about the if statement and the $_ default variable.

Comment: @capser You can also use [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html): `$month = sprintf "%02d", $month`. @cjm I have already posted an answer, and the corrections were not compatible with my solution.

Comment: @TLP, I did see your answer, but you're allowed to post two answers.  Or, you can post one answer that says "here's why what you tried didn't work, and this is how to fix it, but there's an even better method of accomplishing what you want to do."  [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)

Answer (score 5):

If you're happy to use `Date::Calc`, why not use `DateTime` ?

```
use DateTime;
my $date = DateTime->now;
$date->subtract(days => 3);
print $date->ymd;
```

In fact you can reduce that to:

```
print DateTime->now->subtract(days => 3)->ymd
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `printf` instead:

```
printf "%d-%02d-%02d", $year, $month, $day;
```

Gives output such as:

```
C:\perl>perl -we "printf qq(%d-%02d-%02d), 2011,5,4"
2011-05-04
C:\perl>perl -we "printf qq(%d-%02d-%02d), 2011,5,12"
2011-05-12
C:\perl>perl -we "printf qq(%d-%02d-%02d), 2011,22,12"
2011-22-12
```

Comment: I'd say that `%02d` is more idiomatic than `%.2d`.

Comment: And just for symmetry, I generally write `"%04d-%02d-%02d"`.  (A minor point, and one that makes no real difference for years >= 1000.)

Comment: @Keith For computer records, I suppose it would make sense. But if your system requires it, you might have a y10k problem on your hands. ;)

Comment: Not necessarily; `printf("%04d-%02d-%02d", 10000, 01, 10)` will print `10000-01-10`.

Comment: `2011-22-12`?  Is that the 12th of Duodecember?  Are we going to have an `M0.1K` problem on our hands?

Answer (score 2):

if ($month < 10)
{
     $month="0$month";
}
if ($day < 10)
{
     $day="0$day";
}

Comment: yeah i think this is a nice simple and concise way of doing it - thank you

Comment: Please don't. If you hand the result of this over to someplace else Perl will again skip the leading zero because it will handle the string as a number. Use printf for formatted printing.