# command date script shell bsh/ksh

Tags: bash, shell, date, scripting, solaris

I need help.
I made a shell script that you pass a date earlier than 3 days in YYYYMMDD format and tell me if it is correct or not.
My question is. Can i subtract the date command 3 days?
thanks.

Comment: do you want to use the date command to substract 3 days from the given days?

Answer (score 2):

you can test :

```
 DATE="20120803"
 date -d @$(( `date -d "$DATE" +%s` - (3*24*60*60) ))
```

Comment: sorry but ... date: opción no permitida -- d
sintaxis:       date [-u] ddmmHHMM[[cc]aa][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]
date: opción no permitida -- d
sintaxis:       date [-u] ddmmHHMM[[cc]aa][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]

Comment: @canredondocity you shoudn't use the linux tag if your question is not about Linux.

Answer (score 1):

for the fancy solution:

```
INPUT="20120803"
INPUT_SECONDS=$(date -d "$INPUT" +%s)
THREEDAYSAGO_SECONDS=$(date -d "3 days ago" "+%s")

if [ $INPUT_SECONDS -lt $THREEDAYSAGO_SECONDS ]; then
    echo "too early :("
fi
```

Comment: date: opción no permitida -- d
sintaxis:       date [-u] ddmmHHMM[[cc]aa][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]
date: opción no permitida -- d
sintaxis:       date [-u] ddmmHHMM[[cc]aa][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]
too early :(

Comment: Works here. Please provide meaningful error descriptions including your input.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use the date command to do this (see [Guillame's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11793754/12960)) it may be worth considering a scripting language such as Perl to do more complex stuff more efficiently.

e.g. see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7036729/12960) answer, using [Perl](http://www.perl.com) and the `DateTime.pm` module:

```
use DateTime;
my $date = DateTime->now;
$date->subtract(days => 3);
print $date->ymd;
```

Comment: use:  no encontrado
my:  no encontrado

Comment: @canredondocity This is _perl_, not a shell script. And you need the _DateTime.pm_ module.